# WPF application doesn't run (or appear) if api not available

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple WPF application that doesn't appear if api is not available. How do I handle it so screen at least shows up saying no api is available?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetWeather();
    }

    private void GetWeather()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var content = client.DownloadString($"http://localhost:50054/WeatherForecast");

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>(content);

            message4Label.Text = data.ToList()[0].Summary;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MOve the call to the FormLoad event and protect it with a try/catch

Comment: How do you tell it to try several times or wait for a period of time before giving up?

Comment: That's a totally different question, add it to S.O.

Comment: Got it, if you add your first comment I’ll mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move the call from the constructor of the form because if there's an exception it will close the form without any message. Also, protecting the function with a try/catch is always a good idea.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!GetWeather())
           //Present a message to the user
    }

    private bool GetWeather()
    {

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                var content = client.DownloadString($"http://localhost:50054/WeatherForecast");

                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>>(content);

                message4Label.Text = data.ToList()[0].Summary;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch{ return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, there is a Loaded event that I used but there isn't a MainWindow_FormLoad event or a call to that I see. Were you just showing me the concept? There's that in Winforms but not in WPF. Correct?

Comment: @Rod Sorry, you're right, I used the WinForms event instead of the WPF event. Answer updated.